# Ngrx share actions between module boundaries

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, nrwl-nx

I am facing with a nx circular dependencies issue regarding my definition of nx-enforce-module-boundaries lint rule, and this issue is related to ngrx action, where to put them.

I am going to summarise the issue:

I have three different module boundaries: process A and B, with its store, actions, reducers, efffects... and interactions, with its store, actions... too.

The issue is coming because **I have to dispatch an action from process A or process B store (there are different actions) and execute an effect in interaction store which is listening to both actions, process A and B.**

But, I also need some data to display from interaction store in process A and B (I am combining selectors following this article: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts

Thus, I guess that the action should be shared in a different lib from which both stores can import.

Am I correct or there is another best practice to do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem to use the Actions in many sources, and normally you can get the data from the app state that include all the states.
I guess you need to provide more details about the problem or the errors those you got so we can discus them better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).